# How do I query a WPF property from a different thread in C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, wpf, reflection, delegates, c++-cli

I have a piece of C++/CLI code which queries the value of a property of some WPF control using the reflection API, like this:

```
Type ^t = ...;
Object ^o = ...;
PropertyInfo ^p = t->GetProperty( "Enabled" );
Object ^v = p->GetValue( o, nullptr );
```

This worked well, but now I had to move this code to a separate thread. Doing so made the last `GetValue` invocation yield exceptions about accessing the object from a different thread being forbidden.

Knowing that my WPF controls are DispatcherObjects, I know I can use Invoke() on them and pass an Action to have a piece of code executed in the same thread as the target object. However, I don't know how to do this in C++/CLI. In particular, how can I pass a Function (i.e. something which takes arguments and returns a value)?

Ideally, I could do something like

```
// Toplevel code:
delegate Object ^GetPropertyDelegate( Object ^o, PropertyInfo ^p );

// Then, at the place where I perform the GetValue() call:
struct Local {
    static Object ^run( Object ^o, PropertyInfo ^p ) {
        return p->GetValue( o, nullptr );
    }
};

Type ^t = ...;
Object ^o = ...;
PropertyInfo ^p = t->GetProperty( "Enabled" );
DispatcherObject ^dispObj = dynamic_cast<DispatcherObject ^>( o );
Object ^v = dispObj->Dispatcher->Invoke( gcnew GetPropertyDelegate( &Local::run ) );
```

Technically, this compiles - but it doesn't make sense. Ideally, I'd like to have a lightweight (i.e., doesn't require too much code) closure over 'o' and 'p' as something which I can pass to Dispatcher::Invoke. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work. It uses a [`Func<T1, T1, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647%28v=vs.90%29.aspx/html) delegate to call a static method. The method arguments are passed to the `Dispatcher.Invoke` call.

```
public ref class YourClass
{
private:
    static Object^ GetValue(Object^ queryObject, PropertyInfo^ queryProperty)
    {
        return queryProperty->GetValue(queryObject);
    }

public:
    static Object^ GetPropertyValue(
        DispatcherObject^ dispObj, PropertyInfo^ propertyInfo)
    {
        return dispObj->Dispatcher->Invoke(
            gcnew Func<Object^, PropertyInfo^, Object^>(&YourClass::GetValue),
            dispObj, propertyInfo);
    }
};
```

---

The following piece of code does not even require a static method at all. It directly creates a `Func<Object^, Object^>` delegate from the `PropertyInfo` instance and the `PropertyInfo::GetValue` method. Don't know if it's valid C++/CLI, but it works fine for me.

```
Object^ result = dispObj->Dispatcher->Invoke(
    gcnew Func<Object^, Object^>(propertyInfo, &PropertyInfo::GetValue), dispObj);
```

Comment: +1: Ah, interesting - I wasn't aware of `Func`. I'm trying to digest the documentation of what arguments the `Func` constructor takes. Can it only be used to create delegates for objects methods, i.e. not static (class) methods? I tried to adapt your code so that it uses a plain static function `Object ^GetValue( Object ^o, PropertyInfo ^p );` and then pass a `gcnew Func<Object ^, PropertyInfo ^, Object ^>( dispObj, propertyInfo, &GetValue );` to `Invoke`, hoping that I could easily closer over `dispObj` and `propertyInfo` without having a dedicated class...

Comment: @JochenKalmbach And that's exactly what was asked for. `GetValue` has to be called in the UI thread in order to avoid the `TargetInvocationException` mentioned in the question.

Comment: Clemens, you last edit which doesn't even require a static method is pretty sweet! :-) I can't imagine it'll get any better than that, so I'll accept your answer.